# How to dynamically calculate differences between two values in dynamic array?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have next table:

| Quarter | Sum of Qtr |
| --- | --- |
| 30/09/2023 | 1,759,303,572 |
| 30/06/2023 | 1,746,470,053 |
| 31/03/2023 | 1,737,887,307 |
| 31/12/2022 | 1,736,844,945 |

The data in the table based on database "Reserve" formatted as smart table.
The number of rows might be different every time.

The formula for "Quarter" Column is: `=UNIQUE(Reserve[Balance_Date])`

The formula for "Sum of Qtr" is    :

`=SUMIF(Reserve[Balance_Date],Q2#,Reserve[Sum])`

I need to add a new column that calculate the difference between two "Sum of Qtr" rows by formula `=1-R3/R2`.
The question: How can I calculate the difference in "Diff" column as dynamic array?

Need:

| Quarter | Sum of Qtr | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/09/2023 | 1,759,303,572 | 0.73% |
| 30/06/2023 | 1,746,470,053 | 0.49% |
| 31/03/2023 | 1,737,887,307 | 0.06% |
| 31/12/2022 | 1,736,844,945 |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following formula :

[image]

---

```
=VSTACK(1-DROP(R2:R5,1)/DROP(R2:R5,-1),"")
```

---

Therefore your actually formula will be like as following :

```
=LET(α,SUMIF(Reserve[Balance_Date],Q2#,Reserve[Sum]),
 HSTACK(UNIQUE(Reserve[Balance_Date]),
 VSTACK(1-DROP(α,1)/DROP(α,-1),"")))
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

You can exclude the <kbd>VSTACK()</kbd> wrapping as well.

Comment: Thank you!  It didn't work for me with VSTACK(), but did work perfectly with DROP() only.

Comment: @IgorRoytman I am quite not sure, why didnt work with `VSTACK()` may be thats because of arrays, however if you show me a screenshot in the comments below, I may try to fix that as well, but `VSTACK()` not required also, because anyways we are going to leave the last cell blank which eventually the `DROP()` + `DROP()` does the trick!!!